# Projection of Ramthal, India

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, india

I'm working on a project in India and have problem with match shapefile to Google base map. I have tried different projections but couldn't find the right one. 
What is the coordinate system to use in Ramthal area?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have a complete shapefile, there is a `.prj` file, which tells QGIS, which CRS to use.

Comment: the Shapefile that I have doest fit to google base map. I guess that the one that made it didn't give the correct CRS.

Comment: "doesn't fit" is quite unspecific. Can you provide a screenshot? And also the contents of the `.prj` file?

Comment: maybe this pic will explain batter the displacement